# Yii2 REST api pluralize is not working

Tags: php, rest, yii2, pluralize

I have been setting up REST on Yii2 for two days already, and due to different issues and lack of details in documentation I haven't reach my goals yet.

For now I need to make pluralize working for my controller. I can get all users by requesting GET to my

virtualhost/use**r**,

but **404** for:

virtualhost/use**rs**,

virtualhost/use**r/1**,

virtualhost/use**rs/1**.

I have UserController.php  made by  ([official documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-quick-start.md)):

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

I have autogenerated model User, and I have rules, almost the same as in the same quick official guide:

```
...
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [       
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'User'],
    ],
]
....
```

I have tried to set **pluralize** property to true, I even checked, does my **yii\rest\UrlRule** working at all - seems it does not, var_dumps in its init() shows nothing.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you setup `.htaccess` correctly? I've setup REST with default models a few days ago on 2.0.7 it's all works right.

Comment: I did, thanks. I have posted the right answer below, and I am so unhappy that there was no errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem was in controller naming. It is called User, but should be mentioned in rules like 'user', lowercase. I don't know why does developers haven't added any warnings or errors on that thing.